# Objective-C - Creating a shared iADBannerView in a Tabbed Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I am trying to create a shared iADBannerView across multiple View Controllers in a Tabbed Application. I have tried different ways to create this, including Apple's [iAdSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) but have been unsuccessful.

Currently  with my code, which works but I have received errors such as:

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner"

**App Delegate .h**

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <ADBannerViewDelegate>{
    BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}
@property BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *adView;
```

**App Delegate .m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    return YES;
}
```

**View Controller .m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    appDelegate.adView.delegate = self;
    appDelegate.adView.frame = CGRectOffset(appDelegate.adView.frame, 0, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [appDelegate.adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [self.view addSubview:appDelegate.adView];
    appDelegate.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (!appDelegate.bannerIsVisible){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        appDelegate.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.bannerIsVisible){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        appDelegate.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

If anyone has implemented shared iAds, help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit: Found a solution by following this [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=505)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, all you have to do is make a master `UIViewController` with the ad and then use a container view controller with the Tab stuff. See the following links:

Apple documentation on container views:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

This is an awesome library that does all the management for you.
https://github.com/tomohisa/JTCAdBaseViewController